# Is it bad practice to change the state of injected objects?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-injection

Let's say I have the **same instance** of a List injected at multiple different classes across my code. Is it bad practice to manipulate the list (e.g. add/remove items) from within one class so that the other classes can work with that new state of the List? Beside concurrency problems, is it the correct way to communicate changes between my classes? Or should I rather pass the List between functions and the different layers (which could get ugly, if I have to pass a lot of variables across many layers; compared to changing the list in the bottom layer and having the state change wherever the instance is injected, without polluting any method signatures).

Comment: tl;dr: Yes, it's a bad pattern for several reasons, particularly including threading.

Comment: @chrylis -on strike- what are those other reasons?

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better solution would be use synchronized access, this would help in the case of instances change the list at same time, but let me tell you that allow instances direct change the list, is a really BAD practice, the ideal would make the objects immutables, then each instance could work with their own list without problems, but if you need this behavior, in your business logic, I suggest create a persistence strategy, a object that encapsulate the List and make changes on it, globally, without share the state, and then the other instances could get a new copy of the list when it changes, OR yet you can create a sub/notify strategy to notify the instances when the list state change, and then update their list object.

Comment: So, you still suggest to change the state, only through a wrapper of the list? I don't see how this helps avoiding unexpected behaviour. E.g. class A changes list state via the wrapper, but all other classes that have the wrapper injected still don't know where the list's state change comes from, right?

Comment: No, i suggested that you create a persistence strategy, a store, that class would handle the logic of change the list, persist in a file, in-memory database, whatever, and the other classes could call this "wrapper" and get a copy of the current list state, and they could get a new list representation when the list change, (pub/sub hint), the idea is, the behavior won't be unexpected, since you are aware that the list can change and you have to ask the wrapper (this is that save you from unexpected), to give you a new copy. Remember, I said to save it in another location than an object.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. you are right. Mutating the injected object (instance level property) can really turn out to be harmful if you are into any concurrency models.

To communicate with other threads, I would recommend use a persistance that has ACID properties to store and retrieve the state changes.

If you are looking to pass the values between different objects but same thread of execution, you could also try using thread local to store values.
https://dzone.com/articles/painless-introduction-javas-threadlocal-storage

Comment: I'm aware of the concurrency problem. My question aimed more at the design of the communication between the classes ;-) I edited my OP.